# winJS listview error on navigation

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### winJS listview error on navigation

Hi I am working on a WinJS application.I am  using listview to list data.If i navigate to another page before finishing the data loading it shows error like ListView is undefined.How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Need to cancel the worker(promise) before moving to the next page. something like this:

```
unload: function unload()
{
    if (this._loadPromise)
        this._loadPromise.cancel();
},
loadListData: function load()
{
    this._loadPromise = WinJS.xhr(..).then(function onxhrcomplete(req)
    {
        ...
    }).then(null, function onerror(error)
    {
        if (error.message == 'Canceled')
            return;

        // do error handling like showing message box or throw an error object
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok..but i do some dynamic functions for updating listview...That functions still calling after unload the page.How can stop that function?

Comment: only a worker (async promise) can be active. all promises need to be stored as fields and cancelled in unload.

Comment: function AccountSignOut()
    {
        document.getElementById("loginMessage").style.display = "none";
        session.loginStatus = 0;
        session.userName = '';
        session.isSubscribed = 0;
        var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function (sucs, fail, progs) { ShelfViewModel.Loadissues(); });
        
     
    }
    function sucs() {
        var ss = 0;
    }
    function fail() {
        var ss = 0;
    }
    function progs() {
        var ss = 0;
    }

Comment: i didn,t get the complete or progress

Comment: if loadissues returns promise, code need to be something like this - `ShelfViewModel.Loadissues().then(sucs, fail, progs);`

Comment: Still I have the same proble..My loadissue code is  function Loadissues()
    {
        return new WinJS.Promise(function (evt) { 
        if (Internet.isConnected()) {
            if (session.loginStatus == 1) {
                var userName = session.userName;
            }
            else {
                var userName = "";
            }
            
            ShelfModel.RequestIssues(verNo, userName);
        }
        else {
            var s = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Unable to connect to the Internet..Try again..!");
            s.showAsync();
        }
        });
    }